# Navigation bar disappears when come back again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm using a `UINavigationBar` on top of my `TableView`. Whenever I touch a `cell` and come back to the TableView again `NavigationBar` disappears. What shall I do?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if indexPath.section == 0{

             let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: fa_color_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let (fa_ColorArgumentsContent) = fa_color_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text
            cell.textLabel?.text = fa_ColorArgumentsContent
             cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right


            //set the data here
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: fa_system_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let (fa_SystemArgumentsContent) = fa_system_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text
            cell.textLabel?.text = fa_SystemArgumentsContent
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right

            //set the data here
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 2{
            let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: fa_support_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let (fa_SupportArgumentsContent) =  fa_support_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text
            cell.textLabel?.text = fa_SupportArgumentsContent
             cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right


            //set the data here
            return cell
        } else {

            let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let (fa_SupportArgumentsContent) =  fa_color_arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text
            cell.textLabel?.text = fa_SupportArgumentsContent
             cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right

            return cell

    }
```

Comment: do you embed your view controller in uinavigation controller?

Comment: @Tj3n yes,I do.

Comment: write one line in your viewdidapper() that self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

Comment: hmm... it shouldn't just disappear, do you create segue to point back to the viewcontroller after you touch the cell?

Comment: @fatemeh Can u explain a bit more are you pushing another view controller on cell tap and when you come back do u pop that controller ?

Comment: Possibly when you going to detail page on tap of cell in that viewcontroller you are hiding or defaultly getting hide.So on viewDidDisaapear method of detail viewcontroller you need to unhide navigationbar.

Comment: @Tj3n yes, I do

Comment: @ManuGupta yes exactly

Comment: Post code of what you do when the cell is touched

Comment: can you post the snippet of code where u are hiding and unhiding the navbar

Comment: it should be the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: where is your didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod and viewDidDisappear method of next controller or try one more thing assign delegate to navigationController in viewWillAppear method where you are unhiding the navbar

Comment: @Tj3n I don't have one

Comment: Then just remove the segue from your 2nd viewcontroller that pointing back to the 1st viewcontroller that holding the tableview, maybe you create looped segue that is wrong behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

and in next controller use

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

and also

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: what are you doing push or Present ??

Comment: and which line you use for hide the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Assign delegate again to navigationController when you unhide it